# Why does String equals() return false (custom Comparator involved)?

Tags: java, android, string, comparator

I built a very simple custom Comparator, that I use with a TreeSet in order to sort Strings by length in that TreeSet.

I'm having trouble finding the reason why `(s1.equals(s2))` returns false even when the two strings s1 and s2 contain the same value.

Eclipse "variables view" shows the letters are the same in both strings, but the "id" is different, I guess that's why equals returns False.
By the way what is that `id=" "` representing? Is it some kind of pointer to the String object data?

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {

        if(s1.length()<s2.length()) return -1;      
        else if (s1.length()>s2.length()) return 1; 
         return 0; 
        else if (s1.equals(s2)) return 0; //?? ALWAYS RETURNS FALSE
        else if (s1.toString().equals(s2.toString()))//SAME PROBLEM HERE (test)
        else return -1;
    }

    public boolean equals(String s) {
        if (this.equals(s)) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Now here is where I use this custom Comparator:

```
combinations = new TreeSet<String>(new MyComparator());
```

I fill combinations with several Strings, built with the `substring()` method.

Because of the previously mentioned problem, combinations contains duplicates.

When I set NO custom Comparator for this TreeSet, there is no duplicate any more (that's what I want) but it is sorted alphabetically which is normal but not my purpose.

Comment: Won't your implementation of equals() get stuck in infinite recursion?

Comment: can you elaborate on what you want your comparator to do?  It's not clear to me what sort you are trying to accomplish.  Perhaps post some sample output sort data.

Comment: You might also want to look into using the compareTo String method.  http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)   EDIT: Link does not parse correctly because of ")" at the end, but you can find compareTo on that page.

Comment: @Gintautas, good point, I had not realized it could be interpreted as an infinite loop. I was actually assuming that "this" referred to the string S which calls my custom equals() method (Am i wrong ?). But "this" could also refer to MyComparator, in that way I guess the loop would be infinite.

Anyway, I realized in the debugger that the equals() of the comparator method is never called, so it's not the cause of my problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is sort by length but discard duplicates, the following should work.

```
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        int s1Length = s1.length();
        int s2Length = s2.length();
        if (s1Length == s2Length) {
             return s1.compareTo(s2);
        }
        else {
              return s1Length - s2Length;
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strings = {"Hello", "Hello", "longer", "1", "477727357235", "hello"};



    TreeSet<String> set = new TreeSet<String>(new MyComparator());
        set.addAll(Arrays.asList(strings));

        // Won't be duplicates with substrings
        String s = "Hello World";
        set.add(s);
        for (int i = 0; i <= s.length(); i++) {
            String s1 = s.substring(0, i);
            set.add(s1);
        }
        // Still won't be a duplicate, even if we make a copy of the string.
        set.add(new String(s));

        System.out.println(set);
}
}
```

Output: `[, 1, H, He, Hel, Hell, Hello, hello, Hello , longer, Hello W, Hello Wo, Hello Wor, Hello Worl, Hello World, 477727357235]`

Comment: You are absolutely right ! Thanks.
My way of comparing was pretty ugly compared to your code. But anyway I haven't catched yet why it does not work...

Comment: Could you give us some sample words that don't match?  I've tried your code and it seems to work.  You don't need to call toString on strings, because they.. are already strings.  But it won't hurt anything if you do.  But it makes your second comparison to string.equals unnecessary... if their toStrings aren't equal, they are not equal.  And you don't need that fall through - just return the result of them being equal (as I have done).

Comment: I have not tested "independently" my buggy class, but only used it with String inputs generated by a "combination generator" method I use to find anagrams of a word.

You can get more details on sample strings that are causing the problem by viewing the image I inserted in the initial question: http://yfrog.com/2rvariablesproblemj